# Error: "Dimension too large..." when plotting exponentials with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, plot, dimensions

Despite having read answers to 4-5 relate questions, I still can't get why my code does not compile. Here it is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=24cm, paperwidth=35cm, margin=0pt, %
voffset=-50cm, hoffset=-1.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=1]
\draw[very thick,yellow,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi]
plot (\x, {cos((3*\x r)+pi/2)+\x*sin(3*\x r)});
\draw[very thick,orange,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi]
plot (\x, {-0.25*(pow(\x,2)*cos(\x r)-\x*sin(\x r))});
\draw[very thick,green,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi]
plot (\x, {cos(\x r)+\x});
\draw[very thick,magenta,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi]%%          error!
plot (\x, {0.5*(pow(10,-11)*exp(-3*\x)-cos(\x r)+3*sin(\x r))});%% error!
\draw[very thick,blue,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi]%%             error!
plot (\x, {pow(10,-15)*exp(3*\x)});%%                              error!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The latest two of five plots - as I showed in comments - are driving me mad.
Please notice the massive `voffset` too. Is it related?
Obviously I tried several local modifications (e.g. radiants, etc.).
This was just a test but now I'm seriously curious.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The value of the exponential function at `6\pi` is way more than the fixed-point number system used by TeX can handle. You should try using the PGF floating-point library (`fpu`).

Comment: Great, thanks, I see. How do I recall it?

Comment: Actually, this is what the PGF/Tikz manual says about `fpu`: Subsection 36.1
*Note that the library has not really been tested together with any drawing operations. It should be used to work with arbitrary input data which is then transformed somehow into PGF precision.* The `pgfplots` package is your best bet (see percusse's answer).

Comment: Notice that for the 4th function, 10^(-11)*exp(-3x) triggers a value of… 36205484966053 for x = -6pi. Even with fpu, it will be difficult to represent that range of value with yscale = 1!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percusse has answered accordingly to the question. (I think his answer should be marked as "accepted", by the way). I took the liberty to propose a MetaPost solution, however.

Until quite recently, this kind of function drawing would have been impossible to do with MetaPost, since it was based only on quite limited fixed-point numerics. But since its version 1.8 the user can switch to floating-point numerics at will, by setting the internal variable `numbersystem` to `double`. It's still a bit rough around the edges (the default units has not yet been adapted, for example) but it's quite functional, and I couldn't resist to use it for this problem. The following program makes use of LuaLaTeX and its `luamplib` package as a very convenient interface to MetaPost. It calls the Metafun format of MetaPost, which defines the necessary auxiliary functions (cos, sin, exp…)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \mplibnumbersystem{double}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
  input mpcolornames;
  % pi, cm (and mm) as accurate as possible 
  %(defaults settings are too inaccurate: pi = 3.14159265, cm = 28.34645)
  pi:= 3.141592653589793; 
  cm := 3600/127; mm := 360/127; 
  % Unit lengths
  u = .5cm; v = mm; 
  % Graphs boundaries
  xmin = -6pi; xmax = -xmin; xsep = (xmax - xmin)/1000; ymin = -80; ymax = 100;
  % Axes settings
  Xmin = -20; Xmax = -Xmin; Ymin = -85; Ymax = 110;
  % Macro building the graph of a given function f
  vardef graph_of_function (suffix f) (expr xmin, xmax, xsep) =
    for x = xmin step xsep until xmax: (x, f(x)) .. endfor (xmax, f(xmax))
  enddef ;
  % Functions to be graphed
  vardef e(expr x) = cos(pi/2 + 3x) + x*sin 3x enddef;
  vardef f(expr x) = -.25(x**2)*cos x - x*sin x enddef;
  vardef g(expr x) = x + cos x enddef;
  vardef h(expr x) = .5(-cos x + 3sin x + 1e-11exp -3x) enddef;
  vardef i(expr x) = 1e-15exp 3x enddef;
  %
  beginfig(0);
    % Drawing of the given functions
    pickup pencircle scaled 1.25bp;
    draw (graph_of_function(e)(xmin, xmax, xsep)) xyscaled (u, v) withcolor yellow;
    draw (graph_of_function(f)(xmin, xmax, xsep)) xyscaled (u, v) withcolor Orange;
    draw (graph_of_function(g)(xmin, xmax, xsep)) xyscaled (u, v) withcolor green;
    draw (graph_of_function(h)(xmin, xmax, xsep)) xyscaled (u, v) withcolor magenta;
    draw (graph_of_function(i)(xmin, xmax, xsep)) xyscaled (u, v) withcolor blue;
    % Clipping
    clip currentpicture to 
      ((xmin, ymin) -- (xmax, ymin) -- (xmax, ymax) -- (xmin, ymax) -- cycle) 
        xyscaled (u, v);
    % Axes and labels
    pickup pencircle scaled .5bp;
    drawarrow (Xmin*u, 0) -- (Xmax*u, 0); drawarrow (0, Ymin*v) -- (0, Ymax*v);
    label.llft("$O$", origin); 
    label.lft("$y$", (0, Ymax*v)); label.bot("$x$", (Xmax*u, 0));
    % Marking…
    labeloffset := 6bp;
    % … on the horizontal axis
    draw (u*pi, -3bp) -- (u*pi, 3bp); draw (-u*pi, -3bp) -- (-u*pi, 3bp);
    label.bot("$\pi$", (pi*u, 0)); label.bot("$-\pi$", (-pi*u, 0));
    for i = 2 upto 6:
      draw (i*pi*u, -3bp)-- (i*pi*u, 3bp); 
      label.bot("$" & decimal i & "\pi$", (i*pi*u, 0));
      draw (-i*pi*u, -3bp)-- (-i*pi*u, 3bp); 
      label.bot("$" & decimal -i & "\pi$", (-i*pi*u, 0));
    endfor;
    % … on the vertical axis
    for i = 20 step 20 until 80:
      label.lft("$" & decimal i & "$", (0, i*v));
      label.lft("$" & decimal -i & "$", (0, -i*v));
      draw (-3bp, i*v) -- (3bp, i*v);
      draw (-3bp, -i*v) -- (3bp, -i*v);
    endfor;
    label.lft("$100$", (0, 100v)); draw (-3bp, 100v) -- (3bp, 100v);
    % Preventing possible cropping of labels at the figure boundaries
    setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox currentpicture enlarged .5cm;
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This looks very much like what I wanted to achieve, thank you all very much!

Comment: One last thing i don't get is the following. Going back to the comment added by fpast, why my original - and intuitive - code cannot plot exponentials values around y=60 (that would be enough for me) while it plots the orange sinusoid at y=60? Anyway you've been all very welcome, I'll have a lot to study now!

Comment: If you want to stick to `tikz` without using floating-point numerics, the interval must be restricted. Does it break `tikz` if you draw it, say, on the `[-3pi,3pi]` interval?

Comment: in the caso of `plot (\x, {pow(10,-15)*exp(3*\x)});`, I can use -6pi as lower bound of my `domain` but I get the usual error if I choose an upper bound greater than 1.03pi. How many times I thought "with 3pi or similar it should work"...

Comment: `exp(3*1.03*pi)` is approximately equal to `16440.8`. It is probably too much already for `tikz` in fixed-point numerics. For information, the upper limit for MetaPost itself when used in its default fixed-point arithmetics is… `4096`. Conclusion: use `tikz` with `fpu` library, or `pgfplots`, or MetaPost with `double` numbersystem, or Asymptote, or whatever drawing tool with floating-point numerics.

Comment: Ok, true. But (despite all comments and answers opened many ways for a B-plan using LuaLaTeX or pgfplots) it still makes me crazy why, with just TikZ, I cannot render the "blue plot" in a y range where I can render the orange one...

Comment: It's normal that the orange one is correctly rendered: `tikz`has no problem for computing the terms of that function, nor for making their multiplication. For example, `x^2` is not too big in the range of value `-3p…3pi`. Whereas `exp(3x)`, which must first be computed before being multiplied by `10^-11`(which is very small and therefore must be seen by `tikz` als equal to `0`!) becomes fast much, much bigger than `x^2`. Too big for `tikz` and its default fixed-point numerics thus.

Comment: Accepted this answer because the comments really make the point and explain what was not clear to me back in the days. Very useful!

Answer (score 17):

Just simply use [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). TikZ in this case is hopeless to deal with such precision. In fact, I just copy pasted and replaced commands. Also adjusted the y domain to make the plots seen.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi,restrict y to domain =-20:100]
\addplot[very thick,yellow ]plot (\x, {cos((3*\x r)+pi/2)+\x*sin(3*\x r)});
\addplot[very thick,orange ]plot (\x, {-0.25*(pow(\x,2)*cos(\x r)-\x*sin(\x r))});
\addplot[very thick,green  ]plot (\x, {cos(\x r)+\x});
\addplot[very thick,magenta] plot (\x, {0.5*(pow(10,-11)*exp(-3*\x)-cos(\x r)+3*sin(\x r))});
\addplot[very thick,blue   ] plot (\x, {pow(10,-15)*exp(3*\x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was really forgetting to post how I finally handled it: functions domains modified where necessary (see `%% error!` in the question code).

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=24cm, paperwidth=35cm, margin=0pt, %
    voffset=-140cm, hoffset=-1.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}%[xscale=1,yscale=1]
\draw[very thick,yellow,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi]
plot (\x, {cos((3*\x r)+pi/2)+\x*sin(3*\x r)});

\draw[very thick,orange,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi]
plot (\x, {-0.25*(pow(\x,2)*cos(\x r)-\x*sin(\x r))});

\draw[very thick,green,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:6*pi]
plot (\x, {cos(\x r)+\x});

\draw[very thick,magenta,samples=500,domain=-pi:6*pi]
plot (\x, {0.5*(pow(10,-2)*exp(-3*\x)-cos(\x r)+3*sin(\x r))});%

\draw[very thick,blue,samples=500,domain=-6*pi:.8*pi]
plot (\x+1, {exp(2*\x)});%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

By the way I think this could be made even better by using `standalone` documentclass and TikZ command `clip`. I'll post an update next time I must make a plot picture for a full book sleeve!